# Unsupported operand type errors

Tags: python-2.7

New to Python here. I am using LPTHW and trying to figure out why my modification did not work. I wanted to use formatters for ex16

Not sure if the issue here is my formatters or my breaks out of the ""

```
line1 = raw_input("Line1: ")
line2 = raw_input("Line2: ")
line3 = raw_input("Line3: ")

print "I'm going to right these to %r." % filename

target.write(" %r, \n\%r, \n\%r ") % (line1, line2, line3)
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'

Any help or additional info is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

`write` probably returns `None`:

```
target.write(" %r, \n\%r, \n\%r ") % (line1, line2, line3)
```

Should probably be:

```
target.write(" %r, \n\%r, \n\%r " % (line1, line2, line3))
```